# When importing a CSV file of 3 million data in Neo4j is there any way to create the 3 million ratios quickly?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher-3.1

These are the queries I use to load from `.csv` file:

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///products.csv" AS row CREATE (:Product {id: row.idProduct, name: row.name, description: row.description, price: row.price, shipping_price: row.shippingPrice});`

In this consultation I take days to create relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///products.csv" AS row
MATCH (Product:Product {id: row.idProduct})
MATCH (category:Category {id: row.idProductCategory})
MERGE (category)-[:OF_CATEGORY]->(Product);
```

Is there any way to create, or import relationships for millions of nodes?

Comment: Do you have indexes or unique constraints on :Product(id) and :Category(id)? You'll need those to improve your lookup speed for your start and end nodes.

Comment: Ok add indexes: Product (id) and: Category (id) and see what results I get thanks for the help.

Comment: I am also adding relationships with this query

Comment: MATCH (prodcategory:Category {ididRestaurant: prodcategory.idRestaurant})
MATCH (resto:Subscriber {id: resto.id})
WHERE prodcategory.idRestaurant=resto.id
MERGE (prodcategory)-[:DEFINED_BY]->(resto);